# Saving UITabBar settings in StoryBoard

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uitabbar

When I create deafault Tab Bar application in Xcode i get Storyboard, AppDelegate and two Controller for default tabs. And what i want to achieve is to save last opened tab after restarting application e.g I'm doing something in the second tab bar and I need to close app. But when i run it again it automatically opens in the second tab.

I saw in 'The iOS 5 Developer's cookbook' that you need to create new method for this (`tabBarController:didEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed:`) but I have no clue where to put ths as I only have AppDelegate and no Controller for the whole UITabBarController and I'm trying to do this with Storyboard.

Comment: Watch this video from Apple: WWDC 2012 Session 208: Saving and Restoring Application State.

Comment: @user523234 thanks a lot! I hope this movie will solve my problem!

Comment: Btw: if you only want to just auomatically open the last tab then Dipen's answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UITabBarController *tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

// Set selected tab bar Number in UITabBarController Delegate Method
//    - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[tabbar selectedIndex] forKey:@"selectedIndex"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


// Retrive the selectedIndex in Method
//    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
NSInteger selectedIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"selectedIndex"];
//Now set your selected Tabbar
[tabbar setSelectedIndex:selectedIndex];
```